# KSQL - Return records between 2 values

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a table with the following records

```
ab
cd
start
ef
gh
stop
io
start
as
stop
kl
```

I only want the records between 'start' and 'stop' rows to be returned.  The records are in order of a time stamp.  In the example given the results would be ef, gh and as.

Any help greatly appreciated.  I have been struggling with this.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the [`scan` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator).

For example:

```
let _start = "start";
let _stop = "stop";
datatable(dt:datetime, ab:string)
[
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:00), 'cd',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:01), 'start',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:02), 'ef',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:03), 'gh',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:04), 'stop',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:05), 'io',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:06), 'start',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:07), 'as',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:08), 'stop',
    datetime(2021-01-01 10:09), 'kl',
]
| order by dt asc
| scan with 
(
    step s1: ab == _start;
    step s2: ab !in(_start, _stop);
    step s3: ab == _stop;
)
| where ab !in(_start, _stop)
```

| dt | ab |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 10:02:00.0000000 | ef |
| 2021-01-01 10:03:00.0000000 | gh |
| 2021-01-01 10:07:00.0000000 | as |

**update**, based on the question in your comment:

- In order to include `start` and `stop`, simply remove the final line (`| where ab !in(_start, _stop)`)

Comment: Many thanks, how would I change it the query to include start and stop?  I also assume the last line could use the variables _start and _stop.

Comment: please see **update** section in the answer